Unmet dependencies error in R 4.4 installation on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
I am beginner. I'm trying to install latest R 4.4 on Ubuntu 22.04, but I'm running into the following error. How do I solve?
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
r-base-core : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.38) but 2.35-0ubuntu3.7 is to be installed
           Depends: libcurl4t64 (>= 7.28.0) but it is not installable
           Depends: libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.12.0) but it is not installable
           Depends: libicu74 (>= 74.1-1~) but it is not installable
           Depends: libpng16-16t64 (>= 1.6.2) but it is not installable
           Depends: libreadline8t64 (>= 6.0) but it is not installable
           Depends: libtiff6 (>= 4.0.3) but it is not installable
           Depends: libtirpc3t64 (>= 1.0.2) but it is not installable
           Depends: libxt6t64 but it is not installable
           Recommends: r-recommended but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: r-doc-html but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.


You're using a release that is now rather old; with four releases made since then thus your older packages. libc6 | 2.38-1ubuntu6    | mantic          | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x shows mantic or 23.10 contains a package meeting the requirement, as does noble or 24.04.

There are other alternatives, but your current approach is trying to install packages intended for newer systems than you've chosen to use. You need to step back & review steps before your paste & explore alternatives approaches before that paste you copied into your question.   (deb packages are intended to be release specific; other alternatives such as snap, flatpak, appimage, compile from source etc. exist, even less safe options of changing your system into a frakensystem by introducing newer packages but that approach has consequences)

Thank you very much for your valuable comments! I installed R 4.4.
